# intl-tel-input canada flag flag automatically changed into us flag when i enter number

Tags: intl-tel-input

when i select Canada flag and type number without 204 country code, flag automatically change into Us flag and input passes +1  in country code with number.thanks for your response. you can test this scenario at [intl-input-officail-site](http://intl-tel-input.com)

```
$(".contact_form").submit(function(){
  $("#phone-full").val($("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber"));
  console.log($("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber"))
  return false;
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: got to official site dear, when you will select canada flag and type number flag will automatically change  into us flag. i have given link

Comment: You should let the author of the website know about this, but a cursory glance reveals that this appears to be expected behavior since the US and Canada both share a +1 country code.

Comment: okay thanks a lot dear